# Concentration inequality of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds, concentration-of-measure, rademacher-distribution

From wikipedia,

**Multiplicative Chernoff bound**. Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent random variables taking values in $\{0, 1\}$. Let $X$ denote their sum and let $\mu = E[X]$ denote the sum's expected value. Then for any $\delta > 0$,

$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X \geq(1+\delta) \mu) \leq\left(\frac{e^\delta}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\right)^\mu
$$

**My question**

Suppose I have a case where the random values take the value $1$ with a fixed probability $p$ *for every round* and $0$ with probability $1-p$. I was wondering for this particular scenario, if there is a better performing bound than the chernoff bound?

Since the Multiplicative Chernoff bound does not take into account the probabilities of the random variable, I was hoping this additional information could lead to a better performing bound.

Is there anything in the literature related to what I want?

Comment: Chernoff bounds are quite good whenever $p$ is particularly small, i.e. so small that we expect the sum to be approximately Poisson-distributed. However, if this is not the case, Hoeffding bounds can be quite sharp. I have not come across anything truly better however, which is why I am only leaving a comment.